# java.lang.RuntimeException: unkonow schemehttps

Tags: android, ssl, websocket, java-websocket

I am trying to connect websocket server from Android. It is working successfully when doing request to localhost server via **HTTP** call with port. However for hosted server with **HTTPS** it is not working and getting below error.

> 06-08 12:42:44.055 19985-20130/com.package
>   E/WebSocketsConnectionProvider: onError
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: unkonow schemehttps

This code I am using for :

```
mStompClient = Stomp.over(WebSocket.class, "https://api.testapp.com/sc/websocket/?access_token=" + sessionManager.getAccessToken());

mStompClient.topic("/topic/test/" + patientAppointmentItem.getAppointmentId())
    .subscribe(topicMessage -> {
        toast(""+ topicMessage.getPayload());
    });

mStompClient.send("/app/test/" + patientAppointmentItem.getAppointmentId() + "/chat.addUser", obj.toString()).subscribe();

List<StompHeader> headers = new ArrayList<>();
headers.add(new StompHeader(StompHeader.id, id));
headers.add(newStompHeader(StompHeader.USERROLE,sessionManager.getRole()));

mStompClient.lifecycle().subscribe(lifecycleEvent -> {

    switch (lifecycleEvent.getType()) {
        case OPENED:
            Log.i(TAG, "Stomp connection opened");
        break;

        case ERROR:
            Log.i(TAG, "Stomp connection error");
        break;

        case CLOSED:
            Log.i(TAG, "Stomp connection closed");
        break;
    }
});

mStompClient.connect(headers);
```

> NOTE : We have Node js application already using this https websocket
>   service in web application and it is working well. So I believe it's
>   not any proxy issue or other issue with server.
>
> Working Link on localhost server :  http://localhost:8080/sc/websocket
>
> Live server link : https://api.testapp.com/sc/websocket

Please guide if I am doing any mistake.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you finally find a solution?

Comment: Yes we find solution. But now I don't remember exactly because of some back-end issue were there.